# LARAVEL Returning Blank View With No Error

Tags: php, laravel

When I click the link leading to `/[page]/ffacts`, where `[page]` is one of `zagor`, `dylan_dog` or `superman`, I get a blank page.

The view is in `resource/views/[page]/ffacts.blade.php`

These are the routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@home');

Route::resource('zagor', 'ZagorController');
Route::resource('dylan_dog', 'DylanDogController');
Route::resource('superman', 'SupermanController');
Route::get('/zagor/ffacts', 'ZagorController@ffacts');
Route::get('/dylan_dog/ffacts', 'DylanDogController@ffacts');
Route::get('/superman/ffacts', 'SupermanController@ffacts');
```

Code in Controllers:

```
public function ffacts()
{
    return view('Superman.ffacts', compact('superman'));
}
```

Comment: what you code in blade file ???

Comment: there's not enough info to identify your problem. please update the code blocks where you are facing the problem.

Comment: mention the code from where you wanna call this controller

Comment: seems your return view('Superman.ffacts') different from what you state here: resource/views/page/ffacts.blade.php

Comment: `return view('Superman.ffacts', compact('superman'));` Is this blade file's path is correct???

Answer (score 2):

Change it like this:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@home');

Route::get('/zagor/ffacts', 'ZagorController@ffacts');
Route::resource('zagor', 'ZagorController');
Route::get('/dylan_dog/ffacts', 'DylanDogController@ffacts');
Route::resource('dylan_dog', 'DylanDogController');
Route::get('/superman/ffacts', 'SupermanController@ffacts');
Route::resource('superman', 'SupermanController');
```

Problem is, that `/zagor/ffacts` get matched by `Route::resource('zagor', 'ZagorController');` because `resource` generate all routes for all CRUD operations, so also something like this `/zagor/{id}`

And this is matched before your custom. You can also check this by running artisan command: `php artisan route:list`

Comment: what you wrote different here?? @Arxeiss

Comment: Nothing, just changed order :) it is matching from top to bottom. Check my updated answer

Comment: @Arxeiss is right: route declaration order is important, you can search for _Supplementing Resource Controllers_ in the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, if your directory structure is really

`resource/views/page/ffacts.blade.php`

then you will need to be using the following return command for the view

```
public function ffacts()
{
    return view('page.ffacts', compact('superman'));
}
```

To use `return view('Superman.ffacts')` you would need a directory structure of `resources/views/Superman/ffacts.blade.php`

Comment: Unfortunately, you didn't state that in your initial question, so how was I supposed to know that? More information would have helped me provide a more suffice answer.

Comment: Now that you have edited the question to clarify this, it would be also useful to have the code you are trying to return in the blade file, so we can see what you are trying to display based on returning compact('superman') and also seeing the anchor tag with the route declaration would help better understand the path you are taking to correctly call the route in question